# Should Effect return Event?

Tags: typescript, effector

I have simple example here to replicate my problem. I'm trying to create kind of generic client handler. When client connects via TCP server i invoke clientFx effect to create the client instance.

Let's say i will have different TCP servers they all have common clientFx, but different way to handle incoming data. Thats why i have handleData function, which returns 2 events, input event onData and output event onPayload, which returns parsed payload.

I ended here in client.done.watch function, becouse i feel that define handling dataflow inside watch is not correct way to do so.

Is this good way to go or am I totally wrong?

```js
import * as net from 'net';
import { createDomain, createEffect, forward } from "effector";

function handleData() {
    const domain = createDomain();

    const onData = domain.createEvent();
    const onPayload = domain.createEvent();

    const $store = domain.createStore<number>(0);
    $store.on(onData, x => x + 1);

    forward({ from: $store, to: onPayload });

    return {
        onData,
        onPayload
    };
}

const clientFx = createEffect((socket: net.Socket) => {
    const { onData, onPayload } = handleData();

    socket.on('data', onData);

    return {
        clientId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        onPayload
    }
});

clientFx.done.watch(({ result: client }) => {
    client.onPayload.watch((state) => {
        console.log('Store', client.clientId, 'changed to', state);
    });

    forward({ from: client.onPayload, to: saveToDbFx });
});

net.createServer(clientFx).listen(5555);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not catch the context of your question but I'll give it a try. You could ask for additional questions

```
const $clientsMap = createStore({})
const saveToDbFx = createEffect()
$clientsMap.on(saveToDbFx.done, (clients, ({ params })) => {
    return {
        ...clients,
        [params.id]: params
    }
})
function createClient(socket: net.Socket) {
    const onMessage = createEvent()
    socket.on('data', onMessage)
    split({
        source: onMessage,
        match: {
            firstSocketType: firstSocketTypeFilterFn,
            secondSocketType: secondSocketTypeFilterFn
        },
        cases: {
            firstSocketType: saveToDbFx.prepend(firstDataHandlerFn),
            secondSocketType: saveToDbFx.prepend(secondDataHandlerFn),
    })
}
saveToDbFx.watch(console.log)
```